# Conflicting results when computing an FFT using ARM DSP libraries and in MatLab

Tags: c, arm, signal-processing, fft, stm32

I'm trying compute an FFT using an STM32L4 microprocessor but am getting strange results.
I read in a .wav file from an SD card, remove the padding and store 1024 bytes of data in an array.
I have confirmed that this data is correct by way of opening the same wav file in a hex editor on my pc.
When i compute the FFT in MatLab and take the magnitude of it the frequency bin corresponding to the frequency of the input sine wave matches up. This is not the case in my C code (as seen in the Keil debugger i am using). 
There is barely any correlation between the values given by the ARM DSP libraries and the values produced in MatLab, for an exmaple, bin[0] in MatLab = 5.2, bin[0] in C = 131246...Something's up! (See edit...)
I've tried two different versions of the FFT and I'll include both of them below:

```
/* Carry out an FFT on the (correctly formatted) input data */
arm_cfft_f32(&arm_cfft_sR_f32_len1024, inputBuffer, IFFTFLAG, BRFLAG);
/* Calculate the complex magnitude of the FFT */
arm_cmplx_mag_f32(inputBuffer, outputBuffer, FFTSIZE);
```

The deprecated code:

```
arm_cfft_radix4_instance_f32 S;
arm_cfft_radix4_init_f32(&S, FFTSIZE, IFFTFLAG, BITREVERSEFLAG);
arm_cfft_radix4_f32(&S, inputBuffer);
arm_cmplx_mag_f32(inputBuffer, outputBuffer, FFTSIZE);
```

Both result in the same (wrong) values. All of the preprocessing done in C is correct, I form an array FFTSIZE * 2 in length arranged as:
Re[0], Im[0], Re[1], Im[1],...,Re[1023], Im[1023].

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated! 
:)

EDIT:
I have realised that other than the DC bin, the values between the two computations are in fact correlated.
i.e. for both computations bin 47 has the largest value (which makes sense since it's a 1kHz sine wave sampled at 22.05kHz). 
Any ideas why the ARM DSP libraries are scaling the outputs of the bins so much?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth All of the values generated in C are enormous in comparison to those from my matlab script. I'll list the first 10 or so bins as an example. C: bin[0] - 131486, bin[1] - 413.7, bin[2]  - 410, bin[3] - 415, bin[4] - 408. Matlab: bin[0] - 5.2, bin[1] - 5.2, bin[2]  - 5.3, bin[3] - 5.2, bin[4] - 5.3.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I have realised that other than the DC bin the values are correlated (i.e. for both computations bin 48 is the largest value), only all the results from C are massively scaled up. Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: A few thoughts:Are the negative and positive frequencies swapped?  Are you computing mag2 (magnitude squared: doesn't use the sqrt) in one and not the other?

Comment: @rts1 I'm definitely using sqrt(Re^2 + Im^2) for both of the magnitude calculations. I don't think that the negative and positive frequencies are swapped either. It seems the case that every single bin matlab is scaled by 0.015 (roughly). Although I have no idea what might be causing this scaling :(.

Comment: Is there a window (HAMMING, HANNING) or something involved? Ah!  Some FFT routines scale by the size of the FFT on the forward FFT, but not on the inverse.  Or maybe one FFT scales by the size and the other doesn't? (Remember, there's a 1/n multiplier, where n is the size of the FFT)

Comment: Hm: scaling off by 0.015?  Is your FFT of size 64?  Then 1/64.0 is 0.015625 and I'll bet you that's what it is.

Comment: @rts1 Nope, in that particular example the FFT size was 1024. If i understand what you're saying is that its literally just a scaling factor which is implicit and in how the different programs generate an FFT, and therefore can be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

arm_cfft_f32 requires 32-bit float sample data.  Whereas a .wav file usually contains 16-bit little-endian signed integer samples.

Comment: Your thought is that he is losing dynamic range with there conversions?

Comment: @rts1 I guess he is saying data are type-punned when int16 buffers are passed to float functions.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I think you could be correct, In fact the data in my .wav is 8-bit. I created a function which i thought was casting each sample to a float32_t and formatting the data into the required format but maybe it's not behaving as i thought? [Going to attempt to insert my code here.](http://pastebin.com/176BEJF2) Would you be able to take a look at that function and let me know if it's behaving as i thought (taking the 8-bit input data, and interleaving it with zeros in an array of floats)? Thanks.

Comment: I notice you've said they usually use signed integers, i wont have access to the IDE / MCU until Monday but this could potentially be the issue since i've been using uint8_t for all of the calculations.